# How to post data using POST method and in json format using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I m new to this so please bear with me.

I want to call an API which accepts data in POST method and in json format.

Please tell me how to call ajax which will send data in post format and in json.

I have tried this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://domain.com/api',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,            
    success: function (response) {

    }, error: function() {
        alert("Error! Please try again.");
    }
});
```

formData in the above code is in array format.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Just do `data`:`JSON.stringify(formData)`.. that should pass it as JSON

Comment: @SandeepNayak it's not working

Comment: What error do you see? Have you checked the console for any errors?